# How to replace an entire Pandas DataFrame column index-wise?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
df1.index = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']

to_add = pd.Series([7,8,9])
to_add.index = ['row3', 'row2', 'row1']
```

How do I add the `to_add` Series to the `df1` DataFrame index-by-index, in a new column `C`? What if I wanted to replace column `B` with `to_add`, again index-by-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it!

```
>>> df1['C'] = to_add
>>> df1

      A  B  C
row1  1  4  9
row2  2  5  8
row3  3  6  7

>>> df1['B'] = to_add
>>> df1
      A  B  C
row1  1  9  9
row2  2  8  8
row3  3  7  7
```

Comment: Can I be sure that this method will /always/ result in a correct index-by-index concatenation?

Comment: If you have the index names matching between the DataFrame and the Series, then yes.

Comment: Well that is great news. Do you have a link to any Pandas documentation that says this? if so, can you please add to your answer?

Comment: that's kind of the whole point of Pandas - is that data is always index-aligned. it's on the main Pandas DataFrame page, iirc.

Comment: Yes, there's no phrasing the in Pandas docs that I can find to match this exact example, but index-aligned data is one of the fundamental principles behind Pandas. This approach is essentially like a left join.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure with @vk1011 solution which is working fine you could use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and pass `to_add.index` to it:

```
df1.loc[to_add.index, 'C'] = to_add
df1.loc[to_add.index, 'B'] = to_add

In [282]: df1
Out[282]: 
      A  B  C
row1  1  9  9
row2  2  8  8
row3  3  7  7
```